# R read in largish XML file contraining multiple tables

Tags: r, xml

I want to efficiently read in an XML File (200mb in Size) consisting of multiple tables.

Sketch of the Structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:element name="dataroot">
    <xsd:element name="dataroot">
  </xsd:schema>
  <dataroot>
   <TABLE1>
[here comes the data]
   </TABLE1>
   <TABLE2>
[here comes the data]
   </TABLE2>
...
  </dataroot>
</root>
```

How do I read in all or specific tables into a data.frame? And what is probably the most efficient way to do so?

Perhaps as a starter:

```
library(XML)
library(data.table)

xmldoc <- xmlParse("data.xml")

d <- getNodeSet(xmldoc, "//dataroot//TABLE1")

size <- xmlSize(d)

dt <- rbindlist(lapply(1:size, function(i) {
    as.list(getChildrenStrings(d[[i]]))
}), fill = TRUE)
```

works OK but is not particularly fast. How can I do this with `xml2`? The package docs are not particualrly enlightening.

Also, I want to loop over all Tables but couldn't figure out the xpath stuff.

Comment: the `xml2`-package probably... but it's hard to answer without actual sample data...

Comment: having never worked with xml, I would be happy with getting some table into a data.frame/tibble in the first place and start benchmarking later on. An actual sample of the data is not possible.